# emacs - save current buffer list to a text file

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, org-mode

Quite often I need to get a simple text copy of my currently opened files. The reasons are usually:

- I want to send the list to a colleague
- I want to document whatever I am working on (usually in an org document)
- I want to act on one of my currently opened files, on the shell. I need to copy-paste the pathname for that.

The fact is that the usual `buffer-menu` or `list-buffers` provide a convenient menu to navigate the opened buffers, but are very inconvenient to copy-paste to the the terminal the names of the opened files, or to perform any of the actions mentioned above. For example: I can not double-click in a line to select the full path-name, and I can not use the `kill`/`yank` emacs sequence to copy around the path-name.

Summary: I would like a way to export to a text file (or to a new buffer) the list of opened files, without other data; no file size, mode, or any other emacs metadata.

Is there a command for that? An extra package I can install?

### EDIT

Adding solution by Trey Jackson, modified to provide some feedback of what has been done:

```lisp
(defun copy-open-files ()
  "Add paths to all open files to kill ring"
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (mapconcat 'identity 
                       (delq nil (mapcar 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))) 
                       "\n"))
  (message "List of files copied to kill ring"))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command will do the job for you:

```lisp
(defun copy-open-files ()
  "Add paths to all open files to kill ring"
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (mapconcat 'identity 
                       (delq nil (mapcar 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))) 
                       "\n")))
```

Comment: This is it! I can easy paste the kill-ring wherever I am working, and from there to the shell if need be.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the mode of your `*Buffer List*` buffer.  By default, it will be in mode `Buffer Menu`, but changing it to `text-mode` or `fundamental-mode` will remove all the special behavior allowing you to cut and paste from it just like a regular buffer.  The metadata can easily be chopped off with `delete-rectangle`.

Alternatively, you can access the buffer list programmatically with elisp:

```lisp
(dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
  (when (buffer-file-name buffer)
    (insert (buffer-file-name buffer) "\n")))
```

Comment: Although that would be a workable solution, it means too many keystrokes to make it practical. I am using this really often.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly should be able to copy and yank from the buffer list.

e.g. copy everything with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>M-w</kbd> and then yank into a new buffer for editing.